# Did any country adopt a straight pull bolt-action rifle?

Tags: military

I know that Canada developed the Ross-rifle, but was it officially adopted? I'm also interested in adoption not only for infantry, but for any armed forces.

Comment: [Switzerland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmidt%E2%80%93Rubin) and [Austria-Hungary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mannlicher_M1895)?

Comment: But thats only development of the weapon not adoption right?

Comment: Both rifles were officially adopted.

Comment: austria 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mannlicher_M1895

Comment: @Matt: Do you know which forces got these rifles or did all troops get them?

Comment: See wiki links above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Straight-pulls Adopted By A National Army

There's basically three families of successful straight-pull rifles: Mannlicher started it all off, then Schmit-Rubin, and finally the Ross rifle, with the Lee-Navy as a short-lived dead-end.

[image]

*Drawing of a Mannlicher M1886* [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mannlicher_M1886#/media/File:Mannlicher_Gewehr.jpg)

- The [Mannlicher family of straight-pulls](http://candrsenal.com/a-quick-and-dirty-guide-mannlichers-straight-pull-rifles/) were used by Austria-Hungary, and her successor states, as well as armies around the world from 1886 through WWII.

  - [M1886](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mannlicher_M1886) in service with Austria 1886 - 1918? was the first straight-pull adopted by a military.
  - [M1888](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mannlicher_M1888) went as far as [Thailand, China, Philippines, and Chile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mannlicher_M1888#Users).
  - [M1890 Carbine](http://www.hungariae.com/Mann90Af.htm) used by Austria-Hungary and the [Emirate of Afghanistan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emirate_of_Afghanistan).
  - [M1895](http://candrsenal.com/rifle-austro-hungarian-steyr-mannlicher-m-95/) was used by [a large number of armies and police units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mannlicher_M1895#Users) through WWII.

[image: K31]

*Swiss K31* [Source](http://candrsenal.com/rifle-swiss-karabiner-1931/)

- [The Schmidt-Rubin family of rifles](http://candrsenal.com/a-quick-and-dirty-guide-swiss-straight-pull-service-rifles/) including the K11 carbine and the [K31](http://candrsenal.com/rifle-swiss-karabiner-1931/). The Swiss army adopted the [Model 1889](http://candrsenal.com/rifle-swiss-schmidt-rubin-model-1889/) in 1889 and the family stated in front-line service until the K31 was dropped in 1958 but was still used by reserves into the 70s.

  - [K31/42 & K31/43 sniper rifles (video)](http://www.forgottenweapons.com/sniper-rifles/k3142-k3143/)

[image: Ross rifles]

*Three rifles in the Ross family*. [Source](http://guns.wikia.com/wiki/File:Ross.jpg)

- [The Ross rifles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ross_rifle#Users) came about because the Canadians needed rifles, the British wouldn't license the [Lee-Enfield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lee%E2%80%93Enfield), and government shenanigans. Famous for being terrible, you could [reassemble the bolt incorrectly and have it bash you in the face](http://www.forgottenweapons.com/myth-and-reality-of-the-ross-mkiii/), but it was a good sport rifle. By the time they got it in shape the Lee was available. Here's [a video on the Mark III](http://candrsenal.com/primer-episode-014-the-canadian-ross-rifle-mk-iii/).

  - Canada (1905-1916, 1939-1945)
  - Luxembourg (1945)
  - UK
  - Latvia (1919?-?)

[image]

*Inner workings of the M1895 Lee Navy* from its [original manual](http://www.forgottenweapons.com/wp-content/uploads/manuals/M1895-Navy-Lee-manual.pdf) [Source](http://www.forgottenweapons.com/m1895-lee-rifle-manual/)

- And then there's the [M1895 Lee Navy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M1895_Lee_Navy) which is sort of a straight-pull. Best to just [watch a video](http://www.forgottenweapons.com/m1895-lee-navy-salvaged-from-the-uss-maine-at-james-d-julia/). It was fairly short lived, used by the US Navy from 1895 through the Spanish-American and Philippine wars. It's [6mm ammunition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M1895_Lee_Navy#Ammunition) was finicky, and it was quickly replaced by the [M1903 Springfield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M1903_Springfield).

The straight-pull bolt-action rifle turned out to be just a step away from a self-loading rifle. If you're going to have the cost and complexity of a straight-pull, might as well go the extra mile and adopt a self-loading rifle. Many straight-pulls became self-loading or even automatic rifles.

### Honorable Mentions

- The [Mondragon rifle family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mondrag%C3%B3n_rifle) [(video)](http://www.forgottenweapons.com/mondragon-1894-bolt-action-rifle-video/) started as the M1894 straight-pull [(video)](http://www.forgottenweapons.com/mondragon-1894-bolt-action-rifle-video/) but was not accepted. The design became a self-loading rifle adopted by the Mexican army. It was the first self-loading rifle adopted by a military.
- [1925 Italian Prototype by MBT](http://www.forgottenweapons.com/prototype-italian-mbt-1925-straight-pull-rifle-video/) (Metallurgica Brescia gia Tempini), only three were produced. They were incredibly over-engineered and the design was adopted to be semi and fully automatic.
- [Huot Automatic Rifle](http://www.forgottenweapons.com/huot-automatic-rifle/) modified existing surplus Ross rifles with a gas piston to become a drum-fed automatic rifle. This was ordered by the Canadian military, but WWI ended before it was fulfilled.

Answer (score -1):

Switzerland uses Schmidt–Rubin. That's straight pull bolt-action rifle.

Comment: Hi, welcome to History Stack Exchange! This is a good start, but a much better answer would expand on that with some sources and additional information.